# "Error displaying widget: model not found" is shown instead of the plot when opening an existing Python notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I use '%matplotlib widget' to make plots and it just works fine on Jupyter lab (Python).
However, when I open the saved notebook, I see 'Loading widget...' then several seconds later, 'Error displaying widget: model not found' is shown instead of every plot.
Please help me solving the problem. Thank you.
The below is code for reproducing the problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib widget

x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
```

I updated jupyter lab, ipympl and ipywidgets, but nothing changed.

The followings are version numbers after update.
jupyterlab                3.5.2
ipympl                    0.9.2
ipywidgets                7.6.5
python                    3.9.13
matplotlib                3.5.3

Comment: Menu bar "Settings" → "Save Widget State Automatically", save notebook, close, reopen. Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not work for me. I still get the error.  
The jupyter notebook properly showed the plots when loading a notebook. I wonder why jupyter lab doesn't.

Comment: Please open a bug report. If it works for me and thousands other users but not for you it is likely a bug very specific to your setup and more information is needed. It is unlikaly that you will find a solution on SO for this.

Comment: While I was looking for how to open the bug report, I found the installation procedure. Then, I noticed I installed the ipywidget wrongly, which was for the older version of jupyter lab. I reinstalled ipywidget correctly, then the problem was solved.